# How to update an issue in Jira v5.1 from Python script using REST API

Tags: python, rest, jira

I would like to be able to update an issue in Jira v5.1 from a Python script using the REST api. I have the following piece of code to extract the information of an existing issue, which works perfectly:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib
import json

serverURL = 'http://jiraserver.com'

# Get the authentication cookie using the REST API
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
authURL = serverURL + '/rest/auth/latest/session'
creds = {'username' : jirauser, 'password' : passwd}
req = urllib2.Request(authURL)
req.add_data(json.dumps(creds))
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
fp = opener.open(req)
fp.close()

queryURL = serverURL + '/rest/api/latest/issue/SANDBOX-150'
req = urllib2.Request(queryURL)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
fp = opener.open(req)
data = json.load(fp)
fp.close()
```

I would like to extend this to be able to update the same issue, and I have the following piece of code:

```
queryURL = serverURL + '/rest/api/latest/issue/SANDBOX-150'

issueUpdate =  {
    'update': {
        'comment': [
            {
                'add': {
                    'body': 'this is a comment'
                }
            }
        ]  
    }
}
req = urllib2.Request(queryURL)
req.add_data(json.dumps(issueUpdate))
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
fp = opener.open(req)
fp.close()
```

When I try to execute the code, I get the following error message:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
response = meth(req, response)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)

    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default 
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

and the error points back to "fp = opener.open(req)" in my code.

I have tried to search the web to see if I could find out a solution but without luck. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks and regards

Comment: call me crazy but maybe it's something to do with [the 405 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)?

Comment: I'll second Ben Speakmon's jira-python lib. Having done Python REST at least three ways in the last two years I've settled on his library. Seems to work fine in Python 2.6 and 2.7 for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. jira-python seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7.x, I recommend jira-python. It's a Python package that handles the entire REST communication with Jira:

http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I'm currently stuck to Python 2.6. Does this mean I need Python 2.7.x to get around my problems?

Comment: I would look at the `jira-python` source code and see how they implemented issue updating, maybe that'll give you an idea on what you're doing wrong.